# Jboss 4.2.3 GA additional deploy directory

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, ejb, jboss-4.2.x

I have some troubles setting up my jboss 4.2.3 GA. I want a second deploy directory outside the jboss structure in order to place some ejb jars there.
I found a thread with the information but it isn't working.

I opened the `jboss/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml`

and changed

```
  <attribute name="URLs">
     deploy/ 
  </attribute>
```

to

```
  <attribute name="URLs">
     deploy/ 
 file:/C:/dev/deploy/
  </attribute>
```

When I restart the server I get this message:

```
10:27:44,507 WARN  [URLDeploymentScanner] Scan URL, caught java.io.FileNotFoundE
xception: Not pointing to a directory, url: file:/C:/dev/20110803_jboss/server/d
efault/deploy/
             file:/C:/dev/deploy/
```

I am using windows during the development process and later on linux. The example from this page ([link](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/204-jboss-deployment-directory-configuration.html)) is for linux and not windows. I also tried

```
file:///C:/dev/deploy/
file:/C:\dev\deploy\
file:/C:\\dev\\deploy\\
file:C:/dev/deploy/
```

and many other. Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: I figuered it out. There was a "," missing after /deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deployment directories are Comma separated, which is stated in the comment above the attribute you have found:

```
  <!-- URLs are comma separated and resolve relative to the server home URL
     unless the given path is absolute. If the URL ends in "/" it is
```